# osx bash grep - finding search terms in a large file with one single line

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, grep

Is there simple unix command line i can enter which lets me isolate say 512 bytes either side of a search term, even if there is only one "line" in a very large text file?

Ok, this should be easy.

Famous last words.

I'm not that familiar with grep, but it seems it is mainly used to filter out lines in the input that contain search terms.

I have a very large json file that I downloaded that i want to search for a particular term.

before you click the link - it's over 244MB so be warned - it is from
 [the internet wayback machine](https://ia601601.us.archive.org/14/items/webshots-freeze-frame-index/webshots-index-20121231-index.json) and contains lists of zip files of archived photos. i am trying to find mine.

Their web interface is broken, so i found the json file that they make public [here](https://archive.org/details/webshots-freeze-frame-index) - it's the last one on the list.

when i grep looking for my username, it finds it, but proceeds to dump that line to the console. the problem is that line is 244MB long, and it's the only line in the file.

i tried using less, but could not get that to do much - it's very slow, and seems to have the same issue.

is there simple unix command line i can enter which lets me isolate say 512 bytes either side of a search term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is almost what you need, like so:

> sed 's/.*\(.\{100\}eubike.\{100\}\).*/\1/' webshots-index-20121231-index.json

returns this to the console:

> 20121017032138","warc",30012950425],["eusbike","2012-11-11 09:41","20121111040120/webshots.com-user-eusbike-20121111-094102.warc.gz",34212598,"20121111040120","warc",19238806437],["EUSCALDUN","2012-11-17 13:

but and it is a big BUT: you are limited by RE_DUP_MAX to 255 either side. Even for the 100 either side shown it took 16 minutes to process on my macbook pro. Only 2 mins for 10 chars each side. I don't have time to test how long it would take for 255 each side, probably around 50 minutes. The reasons for the limitation are shown in ftp://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/centos0/ics-custom-build/BUILD/nagios-plugins-1.4.13/gl/regex.h

I think you may be out of luck if you want that many chars each side around your search term.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have the json file downloaded, you can perform some file manipulation on it to make it easier to search.

I downloaded the first few hundred bytes of the json file, and I see that file looks like this:

```
["entry1","date1","file1.gz",int1,"string1","string1",int1],["entry2","date2","file2.gz",int2,"string2","string2",int2],[...
```

It looks like each entry is in a separate json array, separated by `],[`. You can use `sed` to replace these characters with a line break.

```
sed 's_\],\[_\]\n\[_g' json_file > json_file_with_breaks
```

This command will insert a line break after every entry, so you will get one entry per line:

```
[... entry1 ...],
[... entry2 ...],
...
```

Output will be saved to a new file, `json_file_with_breaks`. I recommend this because if you need to make multiple searches, running `grep` on the new file will be faster than running `sed` each time and piping output to `grep`. **NB**: the new file will *also* be 244 MB in size!

The next step is to use `grep` to search the new file:

```
grep 'search term' json_file_with_breaks
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more along the lines of your original question

> Is there simple unix command line I can enter which lets me isolate say 512 bytes either side of a search term?

From the `grep` man page:

```
-b, --byte-offset  
      Print the 0-based byte offset within the  input  file  before
      each  line  of output.  If -o (--only-matching) is specified,
      print the offset of the matching part itself.
```

So, you can search for your string like this:

```
grep -o -b 'my search term' json_file
```

Output:

```
1234567:my search term
9876543:my search term
...
```

Each line holds the byte offset from the start of the file of each occurrence of 'my search term'.

You can use `cut -bN-M` to select bytes from the Nth to the Mth in the file:

```
cut -b$((1234567 - 512))-$((1234567 + 512)) json_file
cut -b$((9876543 - 512))-$((9876543 + 512)) json_file
```

---

You can automate the above process with a `while` loop:

```
grep -o -b 'my search term' json_file | cut -d: -f1 | while read pos; do cut -b$((pos - 512))-$((pos + 512)); done
```

This finds all occurrences of 'my search term' in the file, cuts out their positions from the `grep` output, and for every position, cuts out 512 bytes on either side of the match from the json file (for a total of 1024 bytes around the match).